# Can't ssh into my server from home linux but can ssh into same server from windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, webserver

I cannot ssh into my server from one of my Ubuntu installations, but if I use another Ubuntu installation or Windows operating system connecting with SSH works smoothly.

So something is broken in one of my Ubuntu installation and I'm struggling to find the exact problem.

I've tried reinstalling ssh/openssh-client/openssh-*/ssh*.

Here is few lines from verbose output :

```
ssh username@MYSERVERADDRESS -v
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to MYSERVER ([MYSERVERADDRESS]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
packet_write_wait: Connection to MYSERVERADDRESS port 22: Broken pipe
```

Tried many different solutions from googling but never worked any.
Deleted .ssh directory, Deleted /etc/ssh/ssh_config (It was automatically created again with default values).

One more information is that problem isn't from server-side as I can SSH into server using another os and same network.

Update :

1. Firewall disabled
2. Server hosted on cloud
3. I've 3 different machines with dual booted Windows and Linux.
4. SSH working perfectly all machines except one in which Linux is troubling connection, and in same machine using Windows everything working fines.
5. More clear view of point 4 : Total 3 machines each loaded with Linux and Windows (dual boot), and only one machine while running Linux having problem with SSH.

Let me know if you need more data from me (except SERVER ADDRESS and USERNAME).

Comment: Does the server have a firewall that is preventing the Ubuntu machine from connecting to port 22?

Comment: Is `username@MYSERVERADDRESS` the same in all cases?

Comment: Is `SERVERADDRESS` a private IP address (such as one in the range 192.168.x.x), or a public address on the Internet?

Comment: Do both Ubuntus have the same `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `~/.ssh/config`? Does the disconnect come immediately after you connect?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes firewal is installed, but I already tried disabling firewall. not worked.

Comment: @roaima yes 'username@myserveraddress' is same for the all cases. and Its public ip. I'm running web server on it. Everything else is working fine there in server.

Comment: @pfnuesel Yes both files are same, even I also deleted both the file you said but in one its showing error and in other working fine,

Comment: Where do all machines stand physically? Are all on the same network? Could it be that IP addresses are clashing?

Comment: No actually server is hosted on vps. And all of client machines are at distant network.

Comment: @pfnuesel may be its not a serverfault because I can connect to server through ssh on another operating system on same machine (dual boot)

Comment: Does your Linux *client* have a firewall enabled? If so please also disable it for the testing.

Comment: @roaima it is already disabled

Comment: Actually in server logs all attempts are successfully served but after client send one packet on which server never responded. @drewbenn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found solution for this problem (sorry for answering my own question).
I'm answering it because If someone has this problem then he/she can use solution that I found.

Actually problem is on both sides server as well as client side.

Server side problem was that `/home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts` file on server was having invalid entry for Ubuntu installation as both operating system having same hardware id and same ip (static ip) but different keys.

So what I did is :

`ssh-keygen -f /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts -R ip.ip.ip.ip`

In my case ip.ip.ip.ip is static public ip of my network. Execute this command on both server as well as client machine where ip.ip.ip.ip will changed respectively.

I don't what this command does ( I found this solution from googling / trial-error)

You can also copy your client machines known_hosts file to other client machine or operating systems.

Sorry for my bad english.

And If anyone knows what this command does and why this command solved problem, then please tell us ! thank you.

Bingo solved!

Comment: Wow. Well caught. That's an excellent description. Do remember to accept it (when you can).

Answer (score 1):

### Locked out of your server? Get in right back!

Locked out of Server because of :

- Host Key Verification Failed Error
- SSH Bad Config
- Bad Configuration
- Firewall lock down

NOTE: This work for Unix | Linux, not on Windows.

### Let's get started.

Two options available depending on your situation.

Opton 1 : Terminal Access ( *if you can regain terminal access* )

#### Terminal Access Option

Update your system with:

```
sudo aptitude update && aptitude safe-upgrade -y
```

*Or your may use:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Now reinstall you broken ssh

```
sudo apt-get --install ssh -y
```

**You will install updated version!**

To fix **Host Key Verification Failed Error** message, do:

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname
```

.

### Blocked SSH Access? Get in right back!

If you are locked out completely from your server **receiving time out** when trying to connect using ssh due to; **bad firewall configuration, blocked port, disk failure or wrong ssh config, Host Key Verification Failed Error etc.** You will use *Disk Mount* option.

#### Disk Mount Option ( *Remote Server* )

Assuming that you've tried **Remote Reboot, Remote Reset, Remote Hardware Reset** via web interface and the problem persist.

Kindly ask your **Data Center** to give you a **[KVM-Console](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/sw/gui/config/guide/2-0/b_UCSM_GUI_Configuration_Guide_2_0/b_UCSM_GUI_Configuration_Guide_2_0_chapter_0100101.html#concept_326834146851499329)** access and boot your box into a **rescue** mode ( *you may get it for free for 1 hour* )

From console access:
Login:

```
*ubuntu@rescue#*
```

*Mount your disk*

```
    mkdir tempDisk

    mount --bind /dev/xvda2 /tempDisk
    mount --bind /proc /tempDisk/proc
    mount --bind /dev /tempDisk/dev
    mount --bind /sys /tempDisk/sys

    chroot /tempDisk
```

NOTE: Your prompt will change now you are in root

```
**root@your-host#**
```

Investigate the problem and fix it. 
Example update your system to fix potential error.

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get --install ssh -y
```

Fix **Host Key Verification Failed Error** message with:

`ssh-keygen -R hostname`

Done exit back to DKM-Console prompt

```
`**root@your-host#** exit `
```

#### Bank in rescue

```
*ubuntu@rescue#*
```

*Restart your server via same KVM-Console.*

```
*ubuntu@rescue#* shutdown -r now
```

login back normal, and you're good to go.

#### Local Access Option

If you have *local or rack access*, remove your disk, mount it into another working linux of the same version, e.g:

```
***mytech@hostname#***

 mkdir tempDisk

mount --bind /dev/xvda2 /tempDisk
mount --bind /proc /tempDisk/proc
mount --bind /dev /tempDisk/dev
mount --bind /sys /tempDisk/sys
```

Get Access Back with:
    chroot /tempDisk

NOTE: Your prompt will change now you are in root of your server!

```
myServer@hostname#;

sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get --install ssh -y
```

Fix **Host Key Verification Failed Error** message with:

`ssh-keygen -R hostname`

Done exit

```
`**myServer@hostname#** exit `
```

*Remove your disk and plug it back into the original server and **turn her on**!*.

Comment: What evidence is there that the OP has is a broken version of SSH, please?

Comment: No SSH isn't broken, I'm sure about that as its working properly with other machines (or even on same machine but on different OS).

Comment: @MohanSharma so you can connect to it from other Windows Machine not from any linux machine?

Comment: @roaima if he can ssh in from other Windows machine, I don't think ssh is broken.  Mohan should ssh in from Window, then just grade your system and re-install ssh, if the problem persist, check your local firewall rules to ALLOW ssh connect to port (if not default port)

Comment: @LasVegasCoder Not exactly, I was able to ssh into server from linux machine also. Suppose you are having two machine A, B. A is cloud vps and B is client (anywhere in world). Now in machine B user installed two different operating systems linux and windows. When that user tried to ssh into server from windows (machien B) it worked perfectly but when tried from linux (machine B) command shown `broken pipe error`.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder sorry but you're on wrong track (may be). bydway always thanks for help :D

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but its not related to my question. I think ou didn't understood what I asked for. Can you please explain me back what is the problem exactly ? (Sorry i'm learning english thats why you're confused)

Comment: @MohanSharma no problem.   I do understand your question based on your accepted answer.  My answer is useful if you are locked out of your server.  Next time please provide us with a screenshot or exact error message to provide accurate answer without delay.  Normal answer to this question will be `echo "" > /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts` which clears the host then you can now login again from any linux  or window without error.  Have a great weekend

Comment: I've already given an exact log from ssh in initial question. and your answer is still not valid as you're clearing known_hosts file which will again create same problem when I switch operating system on same machine. Thanks :D

Comment: Yes your answer is perfect for someone who locked himself out of box (locally) but its still not applicable for box which is hosted on/by cloud service provider such as Amazon, RedShift etc..

Comment: You are welcome @MohanSharma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64999/discussion-between-lasvegascoder-and-mohan-sharma).

Comment: @MohanSharma if you locked yourself out of any cloud, Amazon, RedShift etc... all you have to do is download you snapshot of that instance as iso, mount it locally and correct the error, upload it back and you are good to go.  This is not about wrong or right.  I have 15+ years as System Administration and Software Engineering when internet is underdog to many... I'm not googling around to provide answer, my answer is based on what I've done severally not guessing.  See my profile on https://stackoverflow.com/users/8516173/lasvegascoder?tab=profile I'm only 8 days here.

Comment: Yes in that case it is the solution of someone who locked out of box (whether it is on cloud or local server) due to ssh problem but I never said that I'm locked out of my box. That's a cool and great experience you're having. I'm heading towards this career.  No-one said that you're googling or guessing. I just said that it's not relavent here as you didn't understood the question in first place correctly. Thanks :D

Comment: Have a great weekend :D

Comment: @MohanSharma I edited my answer to cover general purpose including a fix for your question. Have a great weekend .

Comment: @LasVegasCoder Thank you so much. I really appreciate your effort and time. I learned new thing from you (that we can download snapshot and chroot it) - this will also helpful as in past I was locked out of box and vps provider said there is no way now :D. :D 1+ upvote from me. :))

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure if my problem was exactly the same as yours but It was similar so I'll post my solution.

Preliminary information

- I dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10
- The system I am connecting from and to are on the same local network
- I could not connect to my server from Ubuntu but I could with Windows 10
  with putty

Now on to the solution, it was relatively simple.

So when I was attempting to connect to my server from Ubuntu I use this command `ssh USER@SERVER_NAME` and it just didn't work so I decided to find the local address of my server, I found this from my router. Then I tried this command `ssh USER@SERVER_LOCAL_IP`
and it worked.

Hope this helps some one.

Comment: Judging by the accepted answer, your issue was nothing like the issue that the original poster had.  Your issue is a DNS-related problem, while the other user had an issue relating to host certificates.  Also note that the question shows that `ssh` is able to connect to the server, so the issues are totally unrelated.